# How do I convert the dictionary back to a txt file in python?

Tags: python

This is the part I'm working on.

1. Open the .txt and convert it to a dictionary.
2. Edit the values in the dictionary.
3. Convert dictionary back into the .txt file (in the same format), preserving all the updated information from 2). <-- I'm stuck here

Below is how I open the .txt.

```
with open('myplants.txt') as f:
data = f.read()
dict = {}
for x in data.split('\n\n'):
    key = x.split('\n')[0]
    val = x.split('\n')[1:]
    dict[key] = val
```

The .txt looks like this.

```
Flower name 1
2017-01-01 19:00:00
Plant info

Flower name 2 
2014-02-11 18:10:00
Plant info
```

Comment: What does your `myplants.txt` look like?

Comment: Can you tell us what's wrong with your code or what you expected?

Comment: My code works but I am unable to convert the directory back to the .txt in the original format like above.

Answer (score 1):

Given the way you're *importing* the dictionary (which I'm going to call `my_dict`, to avoid overriding the built-in name `dict`), you should be able to just do the same thing in reverse to *export* the dictionary:

```
with open('myplants_out.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(
        '\n\n'.join(
            f'{key}\n{val}' for key,val in my_dict.items()
        )
    )
```

The data in the original `myplants.txt` is formatted where one line has a key, the next line has a value, and then there's an empty line before the next key/value pair, and so on. This should output in that same format.

Make sure that if the `val` is supposed to be multiple lines long, that you've accounted for that *before* running this. Without knowing how you're manipulating the data in between, I can't say for certain how well this code will work, but if you don't do *anything* between your input code and this output code, the files should end up identical.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Is there a way to format the updated .txt file in the same format as the original .txt file before unpacking it into a dictionary? From what I see, the new .txt file is formatted like a dictionary as opposed to having 1 key/value per line.

Comment: @Timothy I'm not sure what you mean. Can you give an example?